# handling multiple applications with angular cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am interested in being able to bootstrap multiple applications with the angular cli.

Through the angular-cli wiki I was able to find an example
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-multiple-apps

Also I found
https://yakovfain.com/2017/04/06/angular-cli-multiple-apps-in-the-same-project/

I went through the angular-cli.json file and ran

```
    "apps": [
    {
      "name": "app1",
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "app2",
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist2",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main2.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills2.ts",
      "test": "test2.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app2",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
```

I was able to get this to run with the following commands

```
ng serve --app 0
ng serve --app 1
```

My first question with this approach is how would be maintain this in the case that we list several apps in the **angular-cli**?  This will get a bit much to monitor and track.

Also, with this approach would you be better off bootstraping a different module in each main.ts file?

The second way I saw this done was in an example in the comments.
https://github.com/Farata/angular2typescript/blob/master/Angular4/router-samples/.angular-cli.json.

This is more ideal, although I am unable to replicate and identify how all of these applications share the same dist folders and everything else besides name.

With the second approach of sharing everything I am wondering how this different than creating a large number of modules and lazy loading them?

I know this question is very theory based but resources online are very limited and I would be interested in knowing how other developers are attacking this issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If i had several apps in `angular-cli` i would name them like:

```
"apps": [
    {
      "name": "app1",
      "main": "main1.ts",
      ...
    },
    {
      "name": "app2",
      "main": "main2.ts"
    }
]
```

Then to start `app1` we can run either

```
ng serve --app 0
```

or

```
ng serve --app app1
```

I prefer second approach because it's easier to understand which application is running.

> How to monitor them?

You have to know what you're doing:)

> Also, with this approach would you be better off bootstraping a
>   different module in each main.ts file?

It depends on what your application will do. I prefer having different bootstrap modules because this ways i can cut some excess stuff from some of application.

For example i need to have two application with almost the same logic but the second app is just part of first with its own features.

So my second application can bootstrap `SecondModule` that will import some shared between applications modules and its own feature modules.

```
@NgModule({
  import: [
    SharedModule,
    SharedModule2,
    SecondFeature1,
    ...
  ]
})
export class SecondModule {}
```

Moreover for such applications i would create corresponding typescript configs to protect ts compiler (and **expecially ngc compiler**) of doing some redundant work:

**tsconfig.app1.json**

```
files: [
  "main1.ts",
  "path to some lazy loaded module"
]
```

**tsconfig.app2.json**

```
files: [
  "main2.ts"
]
```

> This is more ideal, although I am unable to replicate and identify how
>   all of these applications share the same dist folders and everything
>   else besides name.

I think it's mistake. I would output these applications to different folders.

As question is theory based i would say that if you have quite large application you probably will came across with performance build. And having many applications in one angular-cli application can became nightmare. It's just my opinion and experience on this :)

Comment: Is there a way how to also test the app separately from each other?  I did post a question: [How to test apps separately in a multi-app project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47330580/how-to-test-apps-separately-in-a-multi-app-project) in regards to it, but no answer!

Comment: Can you specify what port to run each app on and run both apps at the same time?

Answer (score 8):

The CLI version 6 now supports this out of the box with simple scaffolding commands. First you create a normal cli project using `ng new root-name`. Then you can add projects within it using `ng generate application sub-app-name`. See their wiki page [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-multiple-projects).

Answer (score 1):

You can use ng generate application command to create separate application. This creates 
'projects' folder with environment same as base application. But there will be shared modules. How will you refer at both places? One option is to use relative path.

This article explains with example 
https://medium.com/disney-streaming/combining-multiple-angular-applications-into-a-single-one-e87d530d6527

I also found one problem with this approach. You need to lazy load sub applications from main application. For this, route path need to be specified in base app.routes.ts file. What if you want to build only base without sub applications? You  need to maintain two versions of app.routes.ts file