# Using Angular CLI, how to generate a component/service in a project with multiple applications support?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am using Angular CLI to support multiple applications within one project.

```
"apps": [
{
  "name": "app1",
  "root": "src/app1",
  "outDir": "dist/app1",
  .
  .
},
{
  "name": "app2",
  "root": "src/app2",
  "outDir": "dist/app2",
  .
  .
}
]
```

But when I am running following command to generate a service

```
C:\POC\test1\src\app1\app>ng g service test --app=app1
```

Service is generated like this

```
create src/app1/src/app1/app/test.service.spec.ts (362 bytes)
create src/app1/src/app1/app/test.service.ts (110 bytes)
```

This is not correct. It should create like

```
create src/app1/app/test.service.spec.ts (362 bytes)
create src/app1/app/test.service.ts (110 bytes)
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [handling multiple applications with angular cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45575372/handling-multiple-applications-with-angular-cli)

Comment: @msanford This question is specific to component/service/directive generation using Angular-cli when using multiple applications. It is not duplicate

Comment: What happens when you execute the command from the root directory (C:\POC\test1)?

Comment: @JBNizet result is same from root directory as well

Comment: What CLI version do you use? And could you provide the whole angular-cli.json? Because your setting is working fine on my Angualr CLI test project.

Comment: @jowey I am using Angular CLI version 1.4.2 I am using VS Code & running the command in CMD terminal. Because of character limit in comment, I can not provide complete angular-cli.json

Comment: @GauravKumar, I'm trying to understand benefits of have more thank one app at a project. have your apps any relationship at runtime? if so, do you need "serve" them separated and using different ports?

Answer (score 0):

I would say you found a bug.
Tested your setting on Angular CLI v.1.2.0 and v.1.3.2 both working fine, but at v.1.4.2 and latest v.1.4.3 I get the same behaviour.

Since the Angular CLI release notes of 1.4.x don't spot any significant changes I guess the behaviour is not intended.
Maybe downgrade for a while or open a bug report.

**EDIT:** The problem was that Angular CLI hardcodes appRoot to `app` which causes the error. This was fixed with [PR 7775](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/7775).

Comment: I'll downgrade for now and open a bug report. Thanks @jowey