# How to test apps separately in a multi-app project?

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular-cli

I have a multi app project. I can run the apps separately with the following command: `ng serve --app <appName> -aot`.

In the other hand I would like to be able to run the test for each app separately the same as running them.

e.g. `ng test --app <appName> --sm=false` But it's doesn't work as expected. The test started always by the first app in the file system.

I have been searching and found out that I might have to change to configuration of the `angular-cli.json` - [Proposal: app-specific karma config](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6008) which make sense... but unfortunately it didn't work also.

---

Any hint please?

Comment: What didn't work also? Did you run thetests using the seperate karma confs? How did you start them?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `--app` parameter. Instead run `ng test <appName>`.

If you check `ng test --help` you get: `usage: ng test <project> [options]`

I am on `Angular CLI: 6.0.0-rc.6`, though.