# How can I prevent multiple applications being served at once by AngularCLI?

Tags: javascript, angular, npm-start

Using

Angular CLI: 1.5.2
Node: 6.10.1

in a Mac OS Sierra,

I have installed several web applications so far. Anytime I do `ng serve`. All of the applications that I have installed in the past are served.

I guess it's the normal behavior. But I don't need that...

How do I "uninstall" old applications that I don't want anymore to be run?

Edited to answer comments:

I run npm start from one of the applications that get served. Actually, I run it from the only application that I'd like to be started. However, as I said, all of the applications get started up.

Some other facts:

- They run under the same port (4200).
- The first application I installed runs without any context in the URI. (http://localhost:4200)
- The rest of the applications are started under the same 4200 port, but I need to complete the URI with the actual context.

Comment: Doesn't sound like normal behavior. Are you running the command from a specific app directory? Interestingly, most questions on the subject involve the inverse situation.

Comment: This may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45575372/handling-multiple-applications-with-angular-cli

Comment: Thanks for your comments, @isherwood. I edited to answer you. As far as I understand, angular-cli is a "each-project" file. I am looking for the configuration file/memory/command/whatever that tells Angular CLI to run one or two or three applications and where to do it.